# Facing a problem with insertBefore Method using Linked List data Structure

Tags: java, methods, data-structures

```
public void insertBefore(T e) {
    if(empty())
    {
        insert(e);
    }
    else
    {
        if(head == current)
        {
            current.next = new Node<T>(current.data);
            current.data = e;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> oldCurrent = current;
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(e);
            current = head;
            while(current != oldCurrent)
                current = current.next;
            newNode.next = oldCurrent;
            current.next = newNode;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

}
```

insertBefore(T e): requires: list L is not full. input: e. results: a new node
containing element e is created and inserted before the current element in the list.
The new element e is made the current element. If the list is empty e is inserted at
the beginning and also made the head element. output: none

insert() method implmention

```
public void insert(T e) {

    Node<T> tmp;
    if (empty()) {
        current = head = new Node<T> (e);
    }
    else {
        tmp = current.next;
        current.next = new Node<T> (e);
        current = current.next;
        current.next = tmp;
    }


}
```

I'm implementing this method as an implementer 
the class Linked List has two nodes a current node and a head when we insert a node the current moves to the newest node added to the list.. and the method retrieve returns the current data in the Current node
My Questions is when i type the following in my main so i can test my Linked List implemention of this method i'm not getting the results which i intended my method so

```
    l.insert(2);
    l.insert(3);
    l.insert(4);
    l.insertBefore(5);
    l.findFirst();
    for(int i = 0;  i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(l.retrieve());
        l.findNext();
    }
```

the result of my Testing : 2345
intended results : 2354

Comment: It is a bit hard to debug without the complete code. Your `insert()` method for example could be buggy and give a wrong `current`....

Comment: I think u are missing a previous node..

Comment: If (head == current) then insert a new node seems to be giving u result

Comment: @C.Champagne i just edited it so you see my code for the insert method

Comment: @CreativeSelf it was just an example. You should post your complete code...if possible

Comment: Thank you @C.Champagne for your effort found an answer have a great day sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `current != head`, you should find the previous node of the current, not current itself. like this:

```
Node<T> prev = head;
while (prev.next != current) {
    prev = prev.next;
}
prev.next = new Node<T>(e);
prev.next.next = current;
```

Comment: oh thanks ! just noticed that when prev = pre.next this will be current !